# I'm getting this error in selenium after updating chrome

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When using Chrome 75 version, I used it well without any error, but after updating to version 76 automatically, I get the following error

```
[2019-08-10 16:11:52] local.ERROR: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-GLEJ40B', ip: '192.168.0.4', os.name: 'Windows 1 
0', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown {"exception":"[object] 
(App\\WebDriver\\Exception\\UnknownCommandException(code: 0): 
sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-GLEJ40B', ip: '192.168.0.4', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown at
Driver info: driver.version: unknown at C:\\Bitnami\\wampstack-7.1.30-
```

I downloaded and replaced the driver from Selenium with version 76 but it's not work
What should i do to make it work the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code instead of `System.setProperty` code and add [WebDriverManager 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) version jar file in your build path, irrespective of browser version, it will work properly.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
dcap.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.merge(dcap);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: I doubt this will help since your answer is java code and the OP has not mentioned or tagged java.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using php, I don't understand and i want know what how to use in php, can you show me an example for php?